# How to add more than one delimiter in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to figure out how to set two delimiters: one is newline and another one is space so when I read numbers from file that is filled like this

```
1 2 3
4
5 
6
```

I get one number by order like `1,2,3,4,5,6`. I'm using read command to read numbers. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check this, if it works: `echo $(cat file_name) |while IFS= read -r var; do echo $var; done`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear but based on the sample and expected output the trivial solution would be to use `tr`:

```
$ cat file | tr '[ \n]' ,
1,2,3,4,5,,6,
```

but there is a space after `5` so you need to use `-s` to *squeeze the repeats*:

```
$ cat file | tr -s '[ \n]' ,
1,2,3,4,5,6,
```

which still leaves you with a nasty trailing comma and a missing newline from the end. That can be handled with `sed` or `awk`. (with *Sapphire and Steel* narrator's voice) *Awk has been assigned*:

```
$ cat file | tr -s '[ \n]' , | awk 'sub(/,$/,"")' # fails if output is just 0
1,2,3,4,5,6                                       # add ||1 or ||$0!="" to fix
```

Wait. Since we started `awk` why bother with the `tr` at all:

```
$ awk '{
    gsub(/ +/,",",p)            # replace space runs with a single comma
    printf "%s",p
    p=(p~/,$/||NR==1?"":",") $0 # 5 followed by space leaves a comma in the end so...
}
END {
    print p
}' file
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Well that turned out looking complicated and I just now noticed you did mention using the `read` command so maybe I'm way off with my solutions and I should've used bash scripting from the beginning:

```
s=""                     # using this neat trick I just learned here ;D
while read line          # read a full line
do 
    for word in $line    # read word by word
    do 
        echo -n $s$word  # output separator and the word
        s=,              # now set the separator 
    done
done < file
echo                     # newline to follow
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Yes, it is Saturday evening and I have no life.

Comment: Fine, here's [the intro to _Sapphire and Steel_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gjHmEUiaxo).